# how to hide\close a webView programatically

Tags: java, android

I have an android activity with a webView.

How can I hide/close this webView?

is this the proper way?

webView.setVisibility(0);

Comment: why 0 ? did you read the documentation for the `setVisibility` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `setVisibility(int visibility)` method that all the various UI components inherit from the `View` class.

The documentation says that it can take either of the three values from `View` class:
1. `VISIBLE`: This view is visible
2. `INVISIBLE`: This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
3.  `GONE`:  This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

Now, use the method as and when needed with the appropriate constants from the `View` class.
Since you want to hide, I believe you will need to use `webView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Answer (score 1):

you can hide any `View` by calling `yourView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` or `yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Difference: `INVISIBLE` means your `View` in not visible anymore, but it still takes its screen space. `GONE` means the `View` is completely hidden and doesn't take any space